# Get the text typed from a user in draftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I have a form on my react app. I want to capture the input from the form from my users and store the text in a state property and then send the text back to my server. I have followed the basic DraftJS tutorial however it gives me a map in my state, instead of just the text needed to send back to the server.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            teamName: '',
            editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
            teamId: '',
            uploadedFileCloudinaryUrl: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = (editorState) => this.setState({ editorState });
    }

<Editor editorState={this.state.editorState} onChange={this.onChange} />
```

Is there something special I have to do to get the text from the editor?

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to send the text to the server? So far your code is only about capturing the state of the editor.

Comment: I just create an object from the state of my form elements and then post the data, but my server will accept a string not a editor instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to send an object to the server and your server only accepts strings. In that case you can use `JSON.stringify`. So to send the editor state to the server you would run `sendToSeverFunction(JSON.stringify(this.props.editorState))` and then decode the string in your server.